# Second half of searching script causing me issues

Tags: google-apps-script

Working on a project that searches based on ID numbers from multiple different sheets and putting them all together on a single sheet summarized for easier viewing but I'm stumped on the second half of this part of the script. After it matches the row with the ID from searching column 1 I was trying to get it to take the values from a list of different columns ("T" and "AG-AK") and put them into my summarized page.

```
function K (){
  var spreadSheet = Spreadsheetapp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tltrainSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName ("TL Training");
  var EEID = tltrainSheet.getrange("C2").getValues(); //Id numbers

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234567")
  var Krecord = ss.getSheetByName("MATRIX")

function lookupk(tltSheet, EEID, ss, Krecord){
  var searchString = ss.getRange(EEID).getValues(); //Id numbers for employee entered in the Training Plan
  var column =1; //column Index
  var columnValues = sheet.getRange(3, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString);
```

Comment: Check the brackets for closing your functions. [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) returns a two-dimensional array of values. You will need to either access the value within this (i.e., use `EEID[0][0]`), or use `getValue()`. I'm not sure how you expect `getRange(EEID)` to work--what do you expect the value of EEID to be?

Comment: Value of EEID was supposed to be whatever Id# was entered on the first sheet (tltSheet) in the 4th line I was trying to get it to take and use that value to search the first column in the second sheet for a match. I apologize for the mess. Not much experience with scripts.

Comment: Is that a [sheet ID?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetId()) A [grid ID?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getGridId()) It seems the only valid argument for getRange() on a Spreadsheet object is [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)) according to the documentation.

Comment: I think you mean you are looking for that value within the sheets? That's not something that is possible with apps script. Take a look through the documentation; especially pay attention to what arguments methods take and what values they return. [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) also takes a testing function. You'll need to `getValues()` and find the index e.g. by looping through them. See [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data) example.

Comment: Can you also include the issue you encountered?

Comment: Note on my above post; Google added a [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) function to GAS last month it seems, which may or may not fulfill what you were looking for in looking for the EEID.